# Why in mobile version fullscreen background images are blurred?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, responsive

Why in mobile version fullscreen background images are blurred (Only on device. )? How can I fix this?

http://www.kreativi.linuxpl.eu/kitchooshop/fr/

Comment: Testing on a 5K Retina iMac the quality of your images is visibly poor.  Could this be a pixel density issue where your already low-res files look worse on "retina-style" displays?

Comment: The images are not blurred in mobile view. I've tested them on FireFox and Chrome. Maybe it's just that you have poor quality images.

Comment: Little thing, why do you call a tab 'Sur nous'. I personaly should prefer 'A propos' ;)

Answer (score 1):

The images are blurred because they have background-attachment: fixed. This property stretch the image to the entire size of the window so on mobile devices they appear to be blurred. To resolve this issue try setting the background-attachment: fixed from a specific size. For example:

```css
.class-with-background{
  @media (min-width: /* size to apply the fixed background */){
    background-attachment: fixed;  
  }
}
```

By using this CSS code you will not lose  any part of the image when viewed on the browser